# Usage of "Let me explain the rationale"

Tags: reasoning

I've come across the expression: "Let me explain to you the rationale..."

My question is: in what context would you use it?  Would you use it as a daily expression? or would you leave it for more formal conversations in more formal contexts (speech, work formal discussion)?

Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a particularly "formal" word - but you might want to avoid it if you think there's a possibility the person you're talking to might not be familiar with it. In which case ***reasoning / thinking*** or even plain ***reason*** might be more suitable, but if you have to assume you're talking to someone with a weak vocabulary you might as well just say *Let me explain **why**.*

Comment: You say you’ve come across that expression before, but I couldn’t find many matches on Google. It’s not very common.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. @J.R. I was actually watching sport on TV when the referee mentioned that word to one of the players to explain his decision.

Comment: @Juan - it makes sense in that context. You really should have mentioned that in your question. Contextual details matter quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

It's rarely used instead of **reason** or **reasoning**.

> Let me explain to you the **rationale**.
>
> Let me explain to you the **reason**.

Both are same but I'd like using **reason** to **rationale**

Comment: People might be inclined to say, “Let me explain why...” as well.

Comment: @J.R.Exactly =)